# Array in C, and its pointer

Tags: c, memory, heap-memory, stack-memory

Old question, but I still have some thoughts though.

```
char * getarrmal(void)
{
    char *str;
    str = (char *)malloc(10);
    str[0] = 'a';
    str[1] = 'b';
    str[2] = 'c';
    str[3] = '\0';
    return str;
}

char * getarrdef(void)
{
    char *str = "hello";
    return str;
}

char * getarrfix(void)
{
    char str[10] = "world";
    return str;
}
```

Three functions. First two will return the string address and the string is stored in heap so that you can continue use it in, for example main() function.

In last function the str is a local variable and the returned str cannot be used.

My question is, when I return in the function which is calling the first two, should I manually free them? It is easy to believe for the malloc case it is true, but I am not sure if it is also the case for char *str = "hello".

If I use getarrdef() and not free its return value, then will I have memory leakage somehow?

Comment: If you allocated it, and you didn't use `malloc` (or one of its cousins) to do so, you don't call `free`.  Simple.

Answer (score 4):

No, you should definitely *not* try to free the second one. It is *not* stored in the heap, rather it's a string literal, and trying to free it is undefined behaviour. From `C++11 7.21.3.3 The free function`:

> ... if the argument does not match a pointer earlier returned by a memory management
>   function, or if the space has been deallocated by a call to free or realloc, the
>   behavior is undefined.

For the first one, yes, it's good practice for the responsibility of allocated memory to pass along with the memory itself. That means if something allocates it and gives it to you, *you* are then responsible for freeing it.

That's the case even if you free it by passing it back to a function like: `delarrmal()` - by doing that, you've given that function responsibility to free it.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply:). Then it is a little bit interesting where is the str stored in the second function, the caller's stack?

Comment: @coldguy, `str` (the pointer) is stored on the stack in the first two cases, and `str` (the array) is stored there for the third case. However, what the pointer _points to_ differs in the first two cases (the third case is irrelevant since str is not a pointer (within the function)). In the first case, it points to the heap, in the second it points to a string literal not in the heap.

Comment: The function or module that allocated memory should free it; passing stuff around to be freed by others is an excellent way to leak memory or crash on double free. But what's most important is to nail down and document the ownership semantics. Of course, if you give up on the obsolete language C, passing ownership around can be done safely, as with C++11's unique_ptr.

Comment: @coldguy string literals are neither in the heap nor on the stack; in most implementations they are in the same place as static and global variables.

Comment: Or, the second function will be the best practice. You can return a string, and you don't need to worry about its memory allocation. Seems wonderful...

Comment: Thanks all the replies. This really clarifies a lot of confusion of me for some long time.

Comment: @coldguy if str were declared static in the third case, that would be safe ... it would be just like a string literal but slightly more efficient because no pointer is needed. But it all depends on use cases. malloc is particularly useful when the size of the thing is unknown at compile time. locals are useful when they won't be used after the function returns.

Comment: @coldguy, the problem with the second case is that you can't _modify_ the string. If you don't need to, that's fine. But many situations will want that. Jim, I have to disagree on the "allocator function should deallocate" simply for situations where you need to use the allocated memory in the caller. Having responsibility follow the memory is an excellent way to prevent double frees or leaks.

Comment: Having responsibility follow the memory means you have to track the responsibility and people get it wrong. (Things like unique_ptr were invented so the compiler would track it so you can't get it wrong.) It also means that the callee has to know how the memory was allocated, which is called "coupling", which is an anti-principle. Freeing in the same module where you allocate is encapsulation. In C++ this in embodied in the RAII principle. Though why I'm talking about basic software engineering principles to a *C programmer*, and in a comment thread, is beyond me. I think I had best stop.

Comment: @Jim: this is C rather than C++ and, while it would be nice, those facilities aren't available. I don't disagree with the idea that you should pass back the pointer to be "freed" by the original module (whetehr that entails `free()` or some other mechanism such as malloc caching or non-malloced memory in some circumstances) since that does _indeed_ increase encapsulation, but the responsibility of the memory still follows the memory in that case - the caller has to call the module's `hereHaveThisBack()` function to release it.

Comment: I of course know what this is. The point is that there are things you can do safely in C++11 that you cannot do safely in C and thus shouldn't. I won't further debate the "follows the memory" bit but I do firmly believe it to be wrong.